# Unable to download secure files conditionally in Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-tasks

**Question**
I am using DownloadSecureFile@1 task to download Secure files.
The issue occurs when in Azure DevOps, in the Library's secure files section, only file_A.txt exists.
The script works fine when both files exists.

In my case, a user A will only need file_A.txt, user B will only need file_B.txt.
Is this an expected behavior? Any possible workarounds to fulfill the use-case?

**Error Message:**
There was a resource authorization issue: "The pipeline is not valid. Job Job: Step fileB input secureFile references secure file file_B.txt which could not be found. The secure file does not exist or has not been authorized for use. For authorization details, refer to [https://aka.ms/yamlauthz."](https://aka.ms/yamlauthz.%22)

**Code:**

```
parameters:
- name: file_name
  type: string
  default: ''
  values:
    - file_A.txt
    - file_B.txt


pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:
    - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
      displayName: Download File A
      condition: eq('${{ parameters.file_name }}', 'file_A.txt')
      name: fileA
      inputs:
        secureFile: 'file_A.txt'        

    - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
      displayName: Download file B
      condition: eq('${{ parameters.file_name }}', 'file_B.txt')
      name: fileB
      inputs:
        secureFile: 'file_B.txt'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the condition on the tasks you can surround the step with an if-statement as described in [use parameters to determine what steps run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runtime-parameters?view=azure-devops&tabs=script#use-parameters-to-determine-what-steps-run)

```
parameters:
- name: file_name
  type: string
  default: ''
  values:
    - file_A.txt
    - file_B.txt

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.file_name, 'file_A.txt') }}:
  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    displayName: Download File A
    name: fileA
    inputs:
      secureFile: 'file_A.txt'        
- ${{ if eq(parameters.file_name, 'file_B.txt') }}:
  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    displayName: Download file B
    name: fileB
    inputs:
      secureFile: 'file_B.txt'
```

However if every user needs exactly one file, a common (and cleaner) option would be to provide the name of the file needed as a parameter. If a secure file is not needed (i.e the parameter is the default empty) the step can be excluded using an if statement

```
parameters:
- name: file_name
  type: string
  default: ''
  values:
    - file_A.txt
    - file_B.txt

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest
steps:
- ${{ if ne(parameters.file_name, '') }}:
  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    displayName: Download Secure File 
    name: secureFileDownload
    inputs:
      secureFile: '${{ parameters.file_name }}'
```

Comment: Can I use 'startsWith' in the condition? It shows that "unexpected symbol"

Comment: Yes, that should be possible. Make sure to quote parameters correctly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#startswith

Answer (score 2):

> Is this an expected behavior?

Yes, this is expected behavior. To turn a pipeline into a run, Azure Pipelines goes through several steps in this order:

1. First, expand templates and evaluate template expressions.
2. Next, evaluate dependencies at the stage level to pick the first
   stage(s) to run.
3. For each stage selected to run, two things happen:

   - **All resources used in all jobs are gathered up and validated for

     authorization to run.**
   - Evaluate dependencies at the job level to pick the first job(s) to
     run.
4. For each job selected to run, expand multi-configs (strategy: matrix
   or strategy: parallel in YAML) into multiple runtime jobs.
5. **For each runtime job, evaluate conditions to decide whether that job
   is eligible to run.**
6. Request an agent for each eligible runtime job.

So, your secure files will be downloaded before evaluating conditions. Please refer to the document about [Pipeline run sequence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/runs?view=azure-devops). As a workaround, you can refer to the sample shared by @danielorn.